# Confused by SwiftUI ViewBuilder restrictions

Tags: swiftui, viewbuilder

I am learning SwiftUI and want to show a hint when the app launches for the first time. However, the code below is not building without the `let _ =` declarations, and I don't understand why:

```swift
var body: some View {
    if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: kIntroAppLaunchedInfoShown) {
        let _ = IntroManager.appLaunched()
        let _ = UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: kIntroAppLaunchedInfoShown)
    }
    // …
}
```

I found [an explanation](https://forums.swift.org/t/whats-let-foo-vs-foo/54529/4) that says:

> view builders happen to support declarations, but not assignments

However, I am not sure why this is the case. It seems strange that I have to enter (in my case) useless code to get the code to build. Can anyone explain why this is necessary?

Comment: When in a struct that conforms to the view protocol, `var body` which is implicitly a `ViewBuilder` is allowed to declare variables and views, and in the end, must return a view. `let _` creates a variable with no name. Swift allows you to call a function when assigning it to a variable. So, using the `let _` syntax allows you to call a function in `var body`. Now, that being said, remove that from `var body` and trigger it somewhere else. View structs should be lightweight, and you should not make a habit of doing that kind of work in there.

Comment: For a further explanation see [Demystify SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/).

Comment: As @Yrb alludes to, ViewBuilder issues aside, you should look at `onAppear` or `task` for how to do side effects like this and not do these things in the `body`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments to your question give a good explanation about why it is not working and the correct way to approach what you're trying to achieve.

To help you a bit further, here is an example of how you could show the hint in the form of an alert. I've moved your launch code into the function `appearing`, which is called when the View is shown for the first time:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var showingHint = false

    private func appearing() {
        if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: kIntroAppLaunchedInfoShown) {
            IntroManager.appLaunched()
            UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: kIntroAppLaunchedInfoShown)
            showingHint = true
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("The body")
        }
        .onAppear(perform: appearing)
        .alert(
            "Hint",
            isPresented: $showingHint,
            actions: {}
        ) {
            Text("Welcome to my app")
        }
    }
}
```